# Trying to use locale.atof() for changing the period in decimals within a dataframe to convert using pivot_tables

Tags: python, string, pandas, locale

Say I have a dataframe which looks as follows. The values within the column `Value` are decimals.

```
df.head()

         ID Key Value
0   A0AVT1  MAHA    4842000
1   A0FGR8  MAHA    3522710
2   A0JLT2  MAHA    283,433
3   A0JNW5  MAHA    356,09677
4   A0MZ66  CEB 37,5
5   A0PJW6  CEB 487,03677
6   A1AG    CEB 10,625567
7   A1L0T0  HAC 12
8   A1L390  HAC 63,946
9   A1X283  HAC 138,25
```

And I want to use the pandas `pivot_tables` to cast the above dataframe, by using `ID` as index and `Key` as the columns with values from column `Value`. And so I tried the following one liner:

```
df2.reset_index().pivot_table(values='Value',index='ID',columns='Key')
```

However, the above one liner is throwing this data error:

```
~/software/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in _cython_agg_blocks(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
   4042 
   4043         if len(new_blocks) == 0:
-> 4044             raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
   4045 
   4046         # reset the locs in the blocks to correspond to our

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Further, I have tried to use the module `locale` to convert the `,` in the `Value` column in my dataframe `df`. Here is what I have tried:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE') #Germany
df.Value.astype(str).apply(locale.atof)
```

And it is throwing the error:

```
TypeError: data type not understood
```

I have tried using astype (float). It did not change anything.

Any help/suggestions are much appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universal way is to set the locale correctly is to let the system find it out from the enviroment:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, '')
```

This yields on my machine:

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, '')
'de_DE.UTF-8'
>>> df.Value.apply(locale.atof)
0    4.842000e+06
1    3.522710e+06
2    2.834330e+02
3    3.560968e+02
4    3.750000e+01
5    4.870368e+02
6    1.062557e+01
7    1.200000e+01
8    6.394600e+01
9    1.382500e+02
```

If you want to set the locale explicitely, you'll have to use different locale strings for Linux and Windows:

**Linux:**

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'de_DE.UTF8')   # or 'de_DE.UTF-8'
```

**Windows:**

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'German') # or 'de' or 'deu' (case insensitive)
```